# Enabling Demographics tracking over Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was looking for a way to enable demographics tracking and reporting over Analytics API. I know that it can be [enabled over admin or reporting tab](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en). But can't seem to find any clues if this is possible over API.

I found what type of data I can fetch from demographic reports using [Dimension & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=api&cats=geo_network).

If there is no way to do this over API is there a way to set default demographics tracking ON for newly created properties ?